# Formulário para mudar valor no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho isso no banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria um formulário que ao clicar no botão `Enviar` mudasse o valor de `pontos` do usuário selecionado. Mas por enquanto só tenho isso, não sei como fazer o código em PHP.

```
    <?php
$connect = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx'); $db = mysql_select_db('xxxxxxx');
```

```html
<form>
Qual usuário deseja mudar?<br>
  <select name="usuario">
    <option value="todos usuários do banco de dados aqui">todos usuários do banco de dados aqui</option>
  </select><br>
 Novo valor:<br>
  <input type="text" name="pts"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As antigas funções `mysql_*` foram removidas do *PHP*. Você deve utilizar `mysqli_*` ou `PDO`. Vou fazer um exemplo utilizando *MySQLi* estruturado.

> Mas por enquanto só tenho isso, não sei como fazer o código em PHP

1) Uma forma simples, é fazer um arquivo com a conexão do banco de dados e incluir ele onde e quando precisar:

Arquivo **conexao_db.php**:

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect(
    // Altere conforme necessário
    'xxxxxxxx',    // Host do banco de dados
    'xxxxxxxx',    // Usuário
    'xxxxxxxx',    // Senha
    'xxxxxxxx'     // Nome do banco de dados
);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf(
        'Erro na conexão com o banco de dados: %s',
        mysqli_connect_error()
    );
    die();
}
```

2) Exibir os usuários no `select`:

Arquivo **index.php**:

```
<?php

require_once('conexao_db.php');

$query = mysqli_query($conexao, 'SELECT * FROM `usuarios`;');

$usuarios = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

<form action="/setpontos.php" method="post">
    Qual usuário deseja mudar?<br>
    <select name="usuario">
        <?php
        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $usuario['ID']; ?>"><?= $usuario['login']; ?></option>
        <?php
        } ?>
    </select><br>
    Novo valor:<br>
    <input type="text" name="pts"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

3) Repare que, no **index.php**, o `action` do `form` é o arquivo **setpontos.php** e o método é `post`. Vamos fazer esse arquivo agora

Arquivo **setpontos.php**:

```
<?php

require_once('conexao_db.php');

$sql_query = (
    "UPDATE `usuarios`
    SET `pontos` = '".$_POST['pts']."'
    WHERE `ID` = '".$_POST['usuario']."';"
);

if (!($query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql_query))) {
    printf(
        'Erro ao executar consulta no banco de dados: %s',
        mysqli_error($conexao)
    );
} else {
    echo 'Pontos do usuário definidos com sucesso!';
}
```

Se você "`Ctrl+C` » `Ctrl+V`" corretamente, tudo deve funcionar. Lembrando que todos os arquivos devem estar no diretório raiz.

Projeto disponível no meu [GitHub/lipespry/sopt-formulario-mudar-pontos-usuario](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-formulario-mudar-pontos-usuario).

Esta é a melhor forma? Não. Mas vai ser um ponta-pé inicial para você entender como funciona.

Comment: Perfeito, Lipe. Muito obrigado mesmo xD

Answer (score -1):

Fala tiago blz, nao trabalho com php, mais trabalho com java, minha dica seria, você buscar pelo id, apos retornar a consulta com os campos você pode fazer um update para o pontos, existem varias formas de update, com valor fixo no proprio codigo(ex: vc possui uma variavel com um valor fixo, vc seta ela "Update 'nome tabela' SET = 'valor da variavel' WHERE id = 'id desejado'" ) ou você pode buscar o ultimo valor da coluna pontos salvar em uma variavel depois fazer o update com a sua variavel com o valor armazenado  e incrementa -- +1, +2  --- assim por diante....

Comment: A teoria é importantíssima, mas: -*"não sei como fazer o código em PHP"*.